# Excel Chart from Multiple Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a bunch of sheets and each one has a value in cell K15 and call K20. How do I make a stacked column chart that shows these values stacked for each sheet?

Forgive my crude drawing, but something like this

[image]

Comment: I know I can use an aggregate sheet, but I'd really like to know if this is possible without one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to use an additional sheet to aggregate your data and locate your chart.  Just create a column for each sheet, with a 3D reference to the appropriate other sheets for that data.  Then, create your chart from this new, aggregated sheet.

[image: multi-sheet chart]

Just below `Sheet4, K20` is the formula to get that particular value.  Just copy, paste and update the values to make sure they're referencing the appropriate cells.  Obviously, you could also use formula's to look up the values based upon your table's column and row labels.

Comment: Yes, I could use an aggregate sheet. But I was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a whole new sheet, but you do need to aggregate the values somewhere.  Excel won't accept a chart series that references multiple sheets for the series-so you need to pull those values together someplace to get them on your chart.

Comment: So basically its not possible in Excel. Thanks, I'll just aggregate the values.